# How to fix a RewriteRule in htaccess to support url's without slashes at the end (/)?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I want to Rewrite the following URLs:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/helloworld/
```

to

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?page=hellworld
```

This following rule works well for do that job:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?page=$1
```

BUT, I have a problem:

When I go to: `http://www.mywebsite.com/helloworld` (look the slash (/) at the end isn't present) that rule doesn't works. But using `http://www.mywebsite.com/helloworld/` works well.

¿What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Add a `?`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1
```

Comment: the ? tells that the character or the collection of chars might be missing; good job guys

Comment: just as a info, the first (.*) stand s for $1, the second one (.*) would stay for $2

Answer (score 0):

Might be better to force a slash, for consistency sake:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Basically, if the URL isn't a file (`!-f`), then it will do the following rules:  if it has a trailing slash, then go where you wanted it to go, and if it doesn't redirect to the same URL with the trailing slash, which, I think, would repeat the rules again and go where you intended.